# categorical characterization of large cardinals

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, set-theory, higher-category-theory, large-cardinals

**Question 1.** Is there a categorical representation of Kunen's inconsistency result?

**Question 2.** Is there a categorical characterization of very large cardinals (in particular for strong and supercompact cardinals)?

**Question 3.**  Is there a categorical characterization of $0^{\sharp}$?

**Remark 1.** A categorical characterization of other large cardinals is also welcome.

**Remark 2.**  Andreas Blass in the paper "Exact functors and measurable cardinals" has proved that the existence of a measurable cardinal is equivalent to the existence of a non-trivial exact functor from the category of sets to the category of sets.

Would you please give references for such matters.

**Remark 3.** The following papers may have some information about the relation between category theory and large cardinals:

1) Adequate subcategories-Isbell

2) Small adequate subcategories-Isbell,

3) Structure of categories-Isbell,

4) Exact functors and measurable cardinals-Blass,

5) Exact functors, local connectedness and measurable cardinals-Adelman & Blass.

Comment: Vopenka's principle has a well-known category theoretic interpretation.

Comment: The interplay of (significantly) large cardinals and category theory has been the focus of recent research of Bagaria and his collaborators. From what I understand (from discussions with him), there were quite a few results in both fields that only needed researchers fluid enough in both ways of thinking to make concrete. For applications of supercompactness, see his paper with  Carles Casacuberta and Adrian Mathias on *Epireflections and supercompact cardinals*, available at his webpage ay ICREA.

Comment: The paper also presents generous references on Vopěnka's principle from a category theoretic point of view. See also their paper with Jiri Rosicky, *Definable orthogonality classes in accessible categories are small*, available at the ArxiV.

Comment: Regarding question 1, Dustin Mulcahey and I are working on an article exploring various senses in which one has or does not have an analogue of the Kunen inconsistency in category theory. But this is not yet ready...

Comment: Dear Prof. Hamkins, it seems to be very interesting. Would you please explain more about your work.

Comment: _Epireflections and supercompact cardinals_ is also available as http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703119

Comment: Here's an old one: in his paper "Adequate subcategories" (Illinois Journal of Mathematics 4 (1960), 541-552, Theorem 2.5), John Isbell showed that the full subcategory of Set consisting of a single countable set is codense if and only if there are no measurable cardinals.

Comment: Misha Gavrilovich and Assaf Hasson have developed some notion of a model category based on models of $\sf ZFC$. They were able to characterize measurable cardinals, and I believe that the covering lemma is expressible by the existence of a certain functor between the category of the model and the category of its $L$. Similarly, I believe, any sharp can be expressed.

Comment: Let's not forget our own Andreas Blass and his old work on the connection between exact endofunctors on $\mathbf{Set}$ and measurable cardinals (to give one example).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I am wondering if you have written any notes about your comment above (joint work with Dustin Mulcahey).

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Unfortunately, Dustin and I have not been in contact in some time, and the article sits almost-ready but not completed.

Comment: [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/206196/2362) is related and I thnk has a few references to results not yet mentioned.

Comment: Weak Vopenka's Principle was formulated category-theoretically in analogy to Vopenka's Principle (One formulation of VP says there is no fully faithful functor $ORD \to C$ with $C$ locally presentable; WVP says there is no fully fatihful functor $ORD^{op} \to C$ with $C$ locally presentable). See Adamek and Rosicky's _Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories_, Def 6.21. It was later [shown to be equivalent](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00284) to "ORD is Woodin" by Trevor Wilson.

Comment: I should also add that Vopenka's Principle has not just one categorical formulation, but many. In my notes based off of Adamek and Rosicky's book, I have counted over100 (though some are predictable variations on others).

Answer (score 4):

In the paper [Proof theory and set theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20116098?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) Takeuti has given such a characterization for measurable cardinals, strongly compact cardinals, supercompact cardinals and even large cardinals.

Let me first  give the characterization for what Takeuti calls an $\omega$-huge cardinal.  Call $\kappa$ is $\omega$-huge if there exists a non-trivial elementary embedding $j: V_\gamma \to V_\gamma$ with critical point $\kappa$ such that $\gamma=\sup_{n<\omega}\kappa_n$ with $\kappa_0=\kappa$ and
$\kappa_{n+1}=j(\kappa_n)$.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category whose objects are the sets $V_\alpha,$ $\alpha$ an ordinal and whose arrows are elementary embeddings. Then the following are equivalent:

1. There is an $\omega$-huge cardinal,
2. there exists a functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ and a nontrivial natural transformation
   $\eta: F \to F.$

Now let give a characterization of measurable cardinals. $\kappa$ is measurable iff there exists a functor $F:\bf Set \to Set$ such that:

1. $F$ commutes with direct limits whose cardinality is $<\kappa,$
2. $F$ commutes with pullbacks and pushouts, and
3. $F$ does not commute with the following simplest direct limit with the cardinality
   $\kappa$:

   $F(\kappa) \neq \operatorname{dirlim} (F(\alpha), (F(i_{\alpha, \beta}))_{\alpha \leq \beta <\kappa}$,

where $i_{\alpha, \beta}$ is the identity map from $\alpha$ to $\beta.$

Comment: So, $\omega$-huge is just I3?