# Formulating Kunen's inconsistency and Reinhardt cardinals in term of category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, soft-question, large-cardinals

It is known that one can formulate certain large cardinal axioms (e.g. Vopenka's principle--see Mike Shulman's answer to Harry Gindi's mathoverflow question "Reasons to believe Vopenka's Principle/huge cardinals are consistent") in terms of Category theory.

Can Reinhardt cardinals (and consequently Kunen's inconsistency result regarding them) be formulated in terms of Category theory as well?  As a 'soft question' I am wondering if such a formulation might show forth (so to speak) any possible "deep inconsistency" (to use Peter Koellner's term) regarding the hypothesis that $ZF+\text{ exists a Reinhardt cardinal}$ is consistent?

Comment: I've been thinking lately it would be a good idea to link elementary embeddings and category theoretic constructions as discussed at eg https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2015/04/five_quickies.html#c048923. One issue to note is that measurables and certain elementary embeddings aren't the same in the absence of Choice, and this makes things _more_ interesting.

Comment: @David: [One link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=583378) and [another link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=973110) are probably worth a mention here.

Comment: @Asaf the example I linked to is obviously the smallest large cardinal described in this way. I'd be very interested to see a topos version of Reinhardt, in the fully intuitionistic, choice-free setting.

Comment: @David: I merely wanted to point out that if we are referring to possible cases that elementary embeddings and ultrapowers are not quite as nicely behaved as in $\sf ZFC$, these two papers should be mentioned. :-)

Comment: It is not really correct to talk about Reinhardt cardinals in mere ZF, since the concept is not first-order expressible in the language of set theory, unless it is self-contradictory (proof: if being Reinhardt were first-order expressible and $\kappa$ is the least Reinhardt cardinal, with elementary embedding $j:V\to V$, then $j(\kappa)$ is also the least Reinhardt cardinal, a contradiction). Rather, formalizing Reinhardt cardinals requires some formal treatment of classes, and so one is working in GB or ZF($j$).

Comment: @Joel: Kinda surprised to see you omitted $\sf KM$! :-)

Comment: Well, KM includes global choice, and so it refutes Reinhardt cardinals...

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I never realized that KM and GB differ in regard to global choice.  I thought the difference between them was just whether the class comprehension axioms allow quantification of class variables, and that the presence or absence of global choice was an orthogonal issue.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, of course the difference you mention is the most important difference. But my understanding of the conventional usage is that when one says Kelley-Morse (KM), one usually means to include global choice, but when one says Goedel-Bernays (GB or NBG), one does not. Goedel-Bernays with choice (usually written GBC or NGBC) means with global choice. After Googling, however, I see that there may not be universal agreement on whether global choice is part of KM, although it does seem to be usually included and it also seems to be part of the original theory in Kelley's book.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for the clarification. If I remember correctly, global choice was in both Kelley's and Morse's axiomatizations, but it was also in Gödel's version of GB (Axiom E, I think); I'm not sure about Bernays, but von Neumann had it in the form "all proper classes are in bijection with V". So it seems the presence of choice in a system named after someone need not agree with its presence in that person's axioms. (That's certainly the case for Zermelo and ZF.)

Comment: That's funny! There may be less standardization of this than I had thought. But I think it will be helpful for us all to push for standardized usage. The issue of global choice in GBC is often discussed, since it is an issue for the conservativity result over ZFC, which would be completely trivial without the "global" aspect, since one could just take definable classes.

Comment: @Andreas: Now I feel less guilty for not thinking about $\sf KM$ as something with global choice included. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that no very satisfying answer to this question is known, so let me just point out that there are a lot of different things one might mean by a "category-theoretic understanding" of a large-cardinal axiom. I am far from an expert, so I hope that others can help flesh this out and correct me, but here are some themes that I happen to have seen in the literature:

1. Set theorists have responded to the paucity of elementary embeddings $V \to V$ by considering elementary embeddings $V \to M$ where $M$ is not $V$. Whereas category theory suggests studying endofunctors $\mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ which satisfy nice properties weaker than being elementary embeddings (actually the first approach can be viewed as a special case of the second, since $M$ is generally assumed to be a non-elementary substructure of $V$, so we can compose $V \to M \subset V$ to get an endofunctor $V \to V$). This approach is much less developed; the only examples I happen to have come across are at the level of measurable cardinals:

   - As David Roberts alluded to in the comments, [Isbell](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255456274) essentially showed that a full subcategory of $\mathsf{Set}$ is [codense](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codense+functor) iff it is not bounded by any measurable cardinal. A subcategory $A \subseteq B$ is codense (when $B$ is suitably complete) iff its *codensity monad* (a certain endofunctor $B \to B$, namely the right Kan extension of the inclusion $A \to B$ along itself) is isomorphic to the identity.  The codensity monad of a full subcategory $A \subseteq \mathsf{Set}$ is the functor $\mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ sending $X$ to the set of $A$-complete ultrafilters on $X$, hence from a category-theoretic perspective, measurable cardinals can be viewed as connected to the study of certain endofunctors $\mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ which are *not* elementary embeddings.
   - Another relationship between endofunctors of $\mathsf{Set}$ and measurable cardinals is Trnková's result (later rediscovered by [Blass](http://msp.org/pjm/1976/63-2/p03.xhtml)) that there is a measurable cardinal if and only if there is a left exact endofunctor of $\mathsf{Set}$ not isomorphic to the identity. Both of these results are related to [Borger's](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404987900417) result that the endofunctor of $\kappa$-complete ultrafilters is terminal among endofunctors of $\mathsf{Set}$ preserving $\kappa$-small coproducts.
2. I'm having a harder time getting a grip on where category-theoretic statements of Vopenka's Principle fit, largely out of ignorance. But it seems like roughly, any ZFC-independent statement about accessible categories is equivalent to Vopenka's Principle, making it hard to see how to generalize the approach. The idea that a large cardinal axiom can be equivalent to a structure axiom about essentially arbitrary classes of first-order models is pretty cool -- I guess this is analogous to having combinatorial statements equivalent to smaller large cardinals. It provides a pretty compelling picture of what Vopenka's Principle *means*.
3. Type theory has a natural categorical semantics. And it's natural to try to formulate large cardinal axioms in terms of the universes in type theory. There's some work on this by [Palmgren](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.221.1318), but I think it's dealt mostly with smaller large cardinal axioms.
4. Let me just throw in another possibility that I haven't seen studied, but which could be. One could look for statements high in consistency strength by asking questions about nice functors between categories that don't model ZFC, such as toposes and geometric morphisms. This might go in the same direction as asking about ZF+Reinhardt cardinals, but much further. I have no idea whether this could be a legitimate source of strong statements. **EDIT** Andreas Blass points out in the comments that there is an example of this at the level of measurable cardinals studied by [Adelman and Blass](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02924847).

Comment: Regarding your first point, every elementary embedding $j:V\to M$ into a transitive class $M$ (and this includes basically all the usual  large cardinal embeddings) is also a $\Delta_0$-elementary embedding $j:V\to V$, simply because every transitive class $M$ is $\Delta_0$-elementary in $V$. The larger large cardinals then insist on greater absoluteness between $M$ and $V$, such as with strongness or supercompactness, and so the usual large cardinal development fits into the paradigm you describe.

Comment: Thanks for citing my paper, but, to give proper credit, I must point out that the main results were discovered earlier by Trnkova and Reiterman. See: Corrections to: “Exact functors and measurable cardinals” Pacific J. Math. 73 (1977), no. 2, 540.

Comment: A special case of your item 4 is the topic of: Adelman, Murray(5-MCQR); Blass, Andreas(1-MI)
Exact functors, local connectedness and measurable cardinals. (Italian summary) 
Rend. Sem. Mat. Fis. Milano 54 (1984), 9–28 (1987).

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Thanks! I've updated my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: @TimCampion:  Is it possible to construe an elementrary embedding from $Set$ into $Set$ as a particular type of endofunctor?  I was looking at equivalances of the axiom of choice in ncatlab that would be of interest to category-theorists and found one in terms of full and faithful functors that might possibly imply Kunen's result--that is, the only elementary embedding from $Set$ into $Set$ (under $AC$, of course, so this would actually be a subcategory of $Set$) is the identity.  If I am correct, this might be a starting point to obtain the answer I seek.

Comment: I think you might need to consider functors which are faithful but not full to get the full strength of these statements. Categorical logic includes many notions of functors between set-like categories preserving varying amounts of structure. The closest to an elementary embedding that I know of is a [logical functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/logical+functor), but it only preserves the meanings of statements that fit into the usual internal logic, i.e. $\Delta_0$ statements. There's a note to this effect [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elementary+embedding#in_structural_set_theory).

Comment: I have seen non-$\Delta_0$ formulas considered in a categorical setting in a few places, including [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3802) (and possibly in some of the theories that include proper classes in [algebraic set theory](http://www.phil.cmu.edu/projects/ast/)). But I'm not sure I've seen the notion of functor preserving the meaning of these sentences considered, though it would probably be a pretty natural extension.

Comment: @TimCampion: What about the use of anafunctors as a means of eliminating the Axiom of Choice.  Might these be of some use in 'breaking the [Axiom of] Choice barrier' (if in fact such exists)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Anafunctors are a way to deal with a lack of choice in your _meta_ theory. But in the Kunen inconsistency, it seems to be choice in the _object_ theory which is used in an essential way. Only if you want to formulate a theory about an elementary embedding _internally_ to your set theory will anafunctors become plausibly necessary.

Comment: @TimCampion:  I am beginning to read through Mike Shulman's paper "Stack Semantics And The Comparison Of Material And Structural Set Theories" you provided the link to, and have a question regarding his lemma 3.3:  "[Let F be a functor--my comment] If F is fully faithful and essentially surjective then A$\vDash$$\phi$ [where A, B are categories and $\phi$ is a sentence in the language of categories (def. 3.1)] iff B$\vDash$F($\phi$)".  Now if one lets A=B=$Set$, then by Shulman's definitions (and if one can formulate the language of set theory in terms of the language of categories--i.e.

Comment: (cont.) def 3.1), then it seems that lemma 3.3 could give (possibly) a partial characterization of elementary embeddings of $Set$ into $Set$.  Does this make sense?  If so, then under what conditions would the converse of lemma 3.3 hold?  If not, what sort of restrictions would be necessary to make 3.3 refer to elementary embeddings?

Comment: Lemma 3.3 basically says that equivalences of categories preserve and reflect the satisfaction of formulas in Shulman's language of categories. I would expect some sort of Lowenheim-Skolem theorem to show that the converse only holds when the category is finite. I haven't really studied the paper in detail, but judging from the result on [this slide](http://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/uqsatalk.pdf#page=45), I might guess that you want a [logical functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/logical+functor) which preserves classifying objects for formulas in the stack semantics.

Comment: @TimCampion:  The slide presentation of Shulman's you provided the link for clarifies matters nicely!  Thanks.  If a logical endofunctor of $Set$ is the same thing as a powerset-preserving $\Delta_0$-elementary embedding of the universe (Joel David Hamkins and Dustin Mulcahey--ask Prof. Hamkins for a copy of the draft of their paper), then how would one characterize $\Sigma_n$-elementary embeddings?  Also, is the defintion of elementary embedding Kunen gives in his paper proving his inconsistency result the definition of $\Delta_0$-elementary embedding?

Comment: I think that a $\Delta_0$-elementary embedding of the universe is implied by a measurable cardinal ([according to Cantor's Attic](http://cantorsattic.info/Measurable), a measurable cardinal is equivalent to an elementary embedding from $V$ to some transitive class $M$, and the inclusion $M \to V$ is always a $\Delta_1$-elementary embedding). I would guess that a $\Sigma_n$-elementary embedding would be given by a logical functor that preserves classifying objects for $\Sigma_n$ formulas in the stack semantics.